# Selecting unique elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<option>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <desc>123</desc>
</option>
<option>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <desc>12345</desc>
</option>
<option>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <desc>123</desc>
</option>
<option>
    <title>EFG</title>
    <desc>123</desc>
</option>
<option>
    <title>EFG</title>
    <desc>456</desc>
</option>
```

Using XSLT, I want to transform it into:

```
<choice>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <desc>123</desc>
    <desc>12345</desc>
</choice>
<choice>
    <title>EFG</title>
    <desc>123</desc>
    <desc>456</desc>
</choice>
```

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a minimal (19 lines) XSLT 2.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into "grouping" to solve this problem. Either the built-in grouping functions of XSLT 2.0, like for-each-group, or, if you're using XSLT 1, the technique called "Muenchian Grouping".

Comment: This has solved an issue i've had for like 3 hours, thanks heaps, for-each-group worked great.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a minimal XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <choices>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*/title" group-by=".">
     <choice>
       <title>
         <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()"/>
       </title>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/../desc" group-by=".">
         <xsl:sequence select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </choice>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </choices>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note** the use of the functions `current-group()` and `current-grouping-key()`

Comment: @Dimitre, could you elaborate on `<xsl:sequence ... />` a bit, what's it purpuse? I have never used it and never had a feeling that I am missing something, but perhaps using it could have saved me some trouble?

Comment: @Patrick: `<xsl:sequence>` is similar to `<xsl:copy-of>`, however it doesn't create copies of the nodes selected in its `"select"` attribute. Rather it produces something like "references" to these nodes. To summarize, `<xsl:sequence>` is more economical and efficient than `<xsl:copy-of>`

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten good answers already. In the chase of brevity, I present my 16 line solution, based on [Dimitres answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728244/selecting-unique-elements-using-xslt/2729682#2729682):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <choices>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="option" group-by="title">
        <choice>
          <xsl:sequence select="title"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/desc" group-by=".">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </choice>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </choices>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the current context node inside `for-each-group` is the first item in the current group, while `current-group()` returns the list of all items in the current group. I exploit the fact that the `title`element is identical for input and output, and copy the first title from each group.

And for completeness, the XSLT 1.0 solution using Muenchian grouping (20 lines):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="title" match="option/title" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="desc" match="option/desc" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <choices>
      <xsl:for-each select="option/title[count(.|key('title',.)[1]) = 1]">
        <choice>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('title',.)/../desc
              [count(.|key('desc', .)[../title=current()][1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </choice>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </choices>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```